# Ruby on Rails, Haml::SyntaxError at /

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am a newbee for Ruby on Rails. 
When I compile, on the browser, it just keeps me same error on index.haml

Haml::SyntaxError at /
Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.

[image]

This is the code,

```
%h1.text-center All images
.row
%ul.list-unstyled
@images.each do |image|
  %li
    %h2=image.title

    %p
      %a.thumbnail{href: image.file, data:{ lightbox: "gallery", title: image.title } }
        %img{src: image.file.url(:small), width: "100%"}

    %p
      %span(class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook' st_url="#{request.base_url}/images/#{image.id}")
      %span(class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet' st_url="#{request.base_url}/images/#{image.id}")
```

I could not find solution when I look up online.
How can I solve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the dash (`-`) that would [tell Haml to evaluate the line as Ruby code](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_).  It's currently seeing `@images.each do |image|` as plain text.  Change to:

```
%h1.text-center All images
.row
  %ul.list-unstyled
    - @images.each do |image|
      %li
        %h2=image.title

      %p
        %a.thumbnail{href: image.file, data:{ lightbox: "gallery", title: image.title } }
        %img{src: image.file.url(:small), width: "100%"}

      %p
        %span(class='st_facebook_hcount' displayText='Facebook' st_url="#{request.base_url}/images/#{image.id}")
        %span(class='st_twitter_hcount' displayText='Tweet' st_url="#{request.base_url}/images/#{image.id}")
```

Comment: @dukej was this the issue for you?